# Как в Android вызвать стандартную обрезку картинки?

Tags: photo, android

В андроид есть стандартная **обрезка картинок**, которая вызывается, если вы хотите назначить контакту картинку, но она для этого слишком большая, хотелось бы узнать, как её можно вызвать.

А ещё было бы лучше, если бы вы посоветовали, как вызвать обрезку, после того, как я сделаю фото, т.е. из моего приложения нужно вызвать **стандартную камеру**, сделать снимок и чтобы далее вызвалась стандартная программа для обрезки фото.

Может, я ошибаюсь, и так не получится сделать, может, я смогу только вызвать камеру, сделать снимок и только потом вызвать обрезку картинок, в принципе не важно, но первый вариант куда более предпочтителен. И хотелось бы ещё узнать, как передать параметры в обрезку картинок, это необходимо делать через **Bundle** при передачи **интента**?

Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: поиск нормальной библиотеки занял 44 секунды.    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20crop%20image%20library&es_th=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
    //indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

Дивайс вполне вероятно может и не поддерживать эту фичу.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш метод работает, но я не разобрался пока что с некоторыми строками, а именно: 

cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

И мне не возвращается Uri перекодированного изображения методом Intent.getData() или мне необходимо доставать другим способом?

Comment: Я разобрался как достать картинку, она хранится Bitmap-ом в Extra данных, необходимо выполнить (Bitmap) Intent.getParcelableExtra("data") и будет счастье, спасибо за подмогу, не хотелось реализовывать свою резку картинок, когда есть стандартные проги, на счёт того, что может не заработать, то не уверен, во всех телефонах есть стандартная галерея (Если это не китайская подделка), там есть небольшой нюанс, если мы конкретно устанавливаем нужное приложения для открытия в методе SetClass():
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904685/unable-to-find-com-android-camera-cropimage-activity-in-android

Comment: Прошу всё же пояснить, для чего устанавливаются вышеописанные строки.
 
        //indicate aspect of desired crop

     cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
     cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

Их использование не очевидно, т.к. это никак не влияло на отображение картинки и параметры обрезки. Если вы знаете, то прошу подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы нельзя было изменять ширину и высоту обрезки, а задать заранее, чтобы пользователь смог только область выбрать?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: это опциональные параметры, указывающие требуемое соотношение сторон, или же тербуемое разрешение картинки... Они могут работать или не работать в зависимости от модели телефона. Все же я рекомендую найти какую-то библиотеку для обрезания, а не использовать недокументированный функционал.

Comment: Ясно, всё равно спасибо, буду использовать это, пока не найду нормальную библиотеку